# Elements with display:none show on load

Tags: jquery, css, nav

For cross browser certainty etc i have used two menus, one for desktop and one for mobile. With media queries I then display the one and hide the other. My problem is, when I ctrl + f5 or navigate to another page on the mobile version the desktop menu shows for a few seconds on load. Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like a javascript thing, can you please post some code? Also, how do you press ctrl+f5 on a mobile device...?

Comment: @David Well he means 'refresh the page' through whatever mechanism is available, but some tablets do have USB ports, so would let you press Control-F5 if you plugged in a keyboard!

Comment: hide both menus in your general css, and show the correct one using media query/js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's called **FOUC** (flash of unstyled content) and the usual cause for it is javascript running on page load. Browsers will hold off on displaying a page for a few seconds (or tenths of a second) before just displaying. Run your site through [webpagetest.org](http://webpagetest.org) and [zoompf.com](http://zoompf.com) to identify issues that are slowing down page load.

To help you in the short term, add a style attribute to the element when you generate the page, and set the value dynamically, e.g. for PHP:

```
<div id="desktop-menu" style="display:<?php echo $mobile ? 'none' : 'block'; ?>">
```

**Edit:** I've just noticed you've tagged the page with `jquery`. Presumably then you are hiding the element with code like this:

```
$(function(){$('desktop-menu').toggle();});
```

That runs when your web browser has **finished** loading the page. The best thing to do in this case is to inline the CSS `diaply:none` as a `style` attribute, and simply dump the jQuery call.

Comment: Thanks a lot man, one question, im not too sure how to toggle the menu on or off using jquery? for your reference: http://memre.loudcrowd.co.za

Comment: See http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/basics/  Note that your menu wraps on my browser (Chrome on Windows, plenty of screen space): http://web.nickshanks.com/stackoverflow/17654251/memre.png

Answer (score 0):

Do you definitely need to have 2 menu's?

I know myself on TrulyCode.com I have 1 menu, but then style it differently via media-queries, it goes from a basic menu bar, to an off screen side bar for mobile.

Before you go trying to find solutions to your 2 menu way, see if you can get the 1 menu fits all style, as it will help with SEO, page speed, and just generally more consistent.

As Nicholas has mentioned, it's just a flash of unstyled content, the browser has got the HTML for the item, but not all the relevant CSS, or JS.

Although, I wouldn't do as Nicholas has suggested with the `display:none` inline, as if JS hasn't loaded/is blocked/disabled then your user will have no menu at all!

Comment: Thanks a lot guys.. Well I have looked at a few responsive menus that size down dynamically then form into a responsive menu, but the majority of them dont work in IE 7. So all I have basically done is hidden the desktop version display:none and responsive nav display:block

Comment: You have to support IE7? I feel sorry for you!

Comment: Worth having a look at http://wicky.nillia.ms/enquire.js/ (Enquire JS) for media query style JavaScript.

Comment: Cool I finally got it fixed - little change on the nav js initialization from (window).load to document.ready

Comment: @AlexanderWigmore I wasn't suggesting display:none on both, I was suggesting that whichever is to be displayed initially have `display:block` and whichever is to be hid initially have `display:none`. Ideally of course, you would have just one menu, but I myself have a web app that has two menus so I know it can be a necessity some times.